# linking two tables

Tags: database-design

I have two table: **job** with jobid, jobdescription, etc and **user** with userid, jobid, name, etc.

What is the best practice to link two jobid to the same userid in table **user** ?

I can do this with a intermediate table that store the entries of the jobs of the same user but I am thinking that is a more elegant solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three Tables - Users, Jobs, UserJobs

Users table contains information pertaining to the user

Jobs table describes the individual jobs

UserJobs table acts as a bridge between your many-to-many relationships using a combination PK/FK of UserID/JobID.

**Example**

```
Users
UserID Name
---------------------------------
1      Doogie Howser
2      Steve Urkel
3      Forest Gump

Jobs
JobID JobDescription
---------------------------------
1     TV Character
2     Movie Character
3     Nerd


UserJobs
UserID JobID
---------------------------------
1      1
1      3
2      1
2      3
3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relation, and the way to achieve that in RDBMS, is to have a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

You'd have 3 tables:

- **job** — **jobid** (PK), jobdescription, etc
- **user** — **userid** (PK), name, etc.  (note, no *jobid* here)
- **userjob** — **userid**, **jobid** (PK composite of both)

Answer (score 0):

I see that TheTXI has already given you a good answer, Adding more to what he says:
What you have is a many-to-many mapping between Users <=> Jobs. And whenever you have this situation you will have to use a mapping table which maps Users and Jobs. Most often a table called UserJobs would be created which would have a composite key containing a jobid and userid. Hope that helps.